# Abstraction of delegates

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Background; this is part of a button system for a dialog menu. Buttons can either take you to new conversation paths or out of the conversation. It uses Event Actions for when a button is pressed to trigger what happens next.

It uses these events by subscribing the 'next operation' to one event, then subscribing a lamda of unsubscribing that event to every other event.

In sudo code where `button_one` and `button_two` are events

```
button_one += SomethingFancy()

button_two += button_one -= SomethingFancy()
```

So the question is: is there a way to abstract a series of these into one function?
This works fine but is messy and unclean, so is there a better option?

**The Program**:

or at least part of it. I took out some unnecessary code

Glossary:

`toggleUI` and its `.Option` are turning on buttons

`dialog` is a scriptable object that holds data for each conversation state.
It has Lists of dialog with a character and the text they speak

`buttonAction` just checks to see if the dialog leads to more text or the end of the conversation

```
   public event Action ButtonOne;
   public event Action ButtonTwo;
   public event Action ButtonThree;

private void PostDialog(ScriptableDialog dialog) {
   if (dialog.OptionOne.Text != string.Empty) {
      toggleUI.OptionOne = true;
      toggleUI.SetButtonText(1, dialog.OptionOne.Text);
      // These chunky chunks
      ButtonOne += () => buttonAction(dialog.OptionOne);
            
      ButtonOne -= () => buttonAction(dialog.OptionOne);
      ButtonTwo += () => ButtonOne -= () => buttonAction(dialog.OptionOne);
      ButtonThree += () => ButtonOne -= () => buttonAction(dialog.OptionOne);
   }
   if (dialog.OptionTwo.Text != string.Empty){
      toggleUI.OptionTwo = true;
      toggleUI.SetButtonText(2, dialog.OptionTwo.Text);
      // These chunky chunks
      ButtonTwo += () => buttonAction(dialog.OptionTwo);

      ButtonTwo -= () => buttonAction(dialog.OptionTwo);
      ButtonOne += () => ButtonTwo -= () => buttonAction(dialog.OptionTwo);
      ButtonThree += () => ButtonTwo -= () => buttonAction(dialog.OptionTwo);
   }
   if (dialog.OptionThree.Text != string.Empty) {
      toggleUI.OptionThree = true;
      toggleUI.SetButtonText(3, dialog.OptionThree.Text);
      // These chunky chunks
      ButtonThree += () => buttonAction(dialog.OptionThree);

      ButtonThree -= () => buttonAction(dialog.OptionThree);
      ButtonTwo += () => ButtonThree -= () => buttonAction(dialog.OptionThree);
      ButtonOne += () => ButtonThree -= () => buttonAction(dialog.OptionThree);
   }
}
```

Little bit of a strange request, but it would be awesome if there was an answer.

I found this video by Sebastian Lague talking about delegates that I think has the answer, but I cant wrap my brain around it yet, so maybe that could help.
https://youtu.be/G5R4C8BLEOc?t=156

I can show of the code somewhere is you want, just let me know.

Comment: In general you shouldn't use lambdas for events since they are not unsubscribable

Comment: My first thought is [Command Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903763/implementing-the-command-pattern-using-c-sharp-action-delegate).

Comment: @derHugo Unfortunately I needed them here since the function being called doesnt match the event itself, it needed separate input data

Comment: @quaabaam hmm, iv never implemented that before, so I'll give it a shot. Thanks man

Comment: I'm just saying that e.g. this `ButtonOne -= () => buttonAction(dialog.OptionOne);` won't have any effect since it is a lambda -> you try to remove a different lambda than the one that is subscribed so nothing changes and the added lambda will still be executed

Comment: @derHugo https://imgur.com/a/F3vuQUQ since I use the button events elsewhere I dont want to change its type to match

Answer (score 1):

> is there a way to abstract a series of these into one function?

It depends on what you mean. You can't pass an event to a method, so (without using reflection, which you should avoid) you can only write a method that is specific to a given event. But you certainly can do that:

```cs
void SubscribeButtonEvents(EventHandler handler)
{
    EventHandler handler2 = null;

    handler2 = (sender, e) =>
    {
        button_one -= handler;
        button_two -= handler2;
    }

    button_one += handler;
    button_two += handler2;
}
```

The key here is to save the delegate instance being subscribed. In the above, there are two handlers that get captured by the lambda created in the method, since (presumably) you really want to unsubscribe both handlers.

Then you call the method like this:

```cs
SubscribeButtonEvents(SomethingFancy);
```

Where `SomethingFancy()` is of course a method with the appropriate `EventHandler` signature.

If you do need to create a single method that can deal with any arbitrary pair of events, then you will need to use reflection. Not advisable, but it can be done.

Of course, there certainly are other possible approaches, many of them likely superior to this. The question is a bit open-ended and arguably should be improved so that it's not. But taking what appears to be the primary question that was asked, the above addresses that exactly.